# Symbolic links invisible in nautilus on network drive

Tags: ssh, nautilus, symbolic-link, nas

I have a qnap nas TS-219P II, which I can access through my local network.

However when creating symbolic links through `ssh` on the `nas` itself they are not visible in nautilus.

The links are visible via `ssh` and `ls` on the `nas`, however not via a terminal which I opened from nautilus via the context menu (open in terminal).

The web interface of the `nas` itself also does not show the symbolic links.

Creating symbolic links from Ubuntu fails:

> ln: failed to create symbolic link 'filename': Operation not supported

Hard links work as expected. But I want them to break when moving the file, so I want to use symbolic links.

What am I doing wrong?
Why can't I see the symbolic links?
Why can't I create them from Ubuntu?
Why are they only visible via `ssh`?

Could it be that the `nas` itself has such a limited linux variant that symbolic links dont really work?

I know my question is rather vague, I dont know what I'm doing wrong and I'd appreciate some help.